# WCF is adding as a Webreference proxy in client

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, service-reference

I have created a WCF for my application. When i tried to add the service using `AddServiceReference` to my client WebApplication its getting added as a "WebReference" inside a folder named "App_WebReference" not as a ServiceReference. But when i created a new web application and add the same WCF, its getting added as a service reference.

Any ideas where i'm wrong in my previous application?

Comment: You are using a web site "project". Don't do that. They do bizarre things like this. Use a Web Application Project by using "File->New Project".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: May be you are right. I have created a website instead of web application. Let me try.